# Stream and zip to S3 from AWS Lambda Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

My goal is to create a large gzipped text file and put it into S3.

The file contents consist of blocks which I read in a loop from another source.

Because of the size of this file I can not hold all data in memory, so I need to somehow stream it directly to S3 and ZIP at the same time.

I understand how to perform this trick with the regular `fs` in Node.JS, but I am confused about whether is it possible to do the same trick with S3 from AWS Lambda? I know that `s3.putObject` [can consume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) `streamObject`, but it seems to me that this stream should be already finalized when I perform `putObject` operation, what can cause exceeding of the allowed memory.

Comment: Is the gzipped file larger than fits in Lambda ephemeral disk (512 MB)?

Comment: @jarmod probably no, but let's say that I am limited by 128Mb lambda

Comment: If you can ingest the entire text file, persist in gzip format to local disk, and upload that to S3 all within the Lambda timeout then that should be simple enough. You can presumably use multipart uploads to S3 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) to avoid the problem of not being able to read the entire file into memory at one time.

Comment: Where is the file located? It is available locally to app or it need to read via http? What is the size of file we are talking here?

Comment: So the solution is essentially to store everything in memory (ephemeral disk for instance), right?

Comment: @Kannaiyan The size is unknown, but it is generally unlimited, as I am processing some large list of external data sources and aggregate them in one file on S3.

Comment: Where does those large list of files live?

Comment: @Kannaiyan Why does it matter?

Comment: Subject is too broad to answer. And Lambda is not intended to deal with huge data or huge processing time.

Answer (score 7):

You can stream files (>5mb) into S3 buckets in chunks using [multipart upload functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) in the NodeJs [aws-sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html).

This is not only useful for streaming large files into buckets, but also enables you to **retry** failed chunks (instead of a whole file) and **parallelize** upload of individual chunks (with multiple, upload lambdas, which could be useful in a serverless ETL setup for example). The order in which they arrive is not important as long as you track them and finalize the process once all have been uploaded.

To use the multipart upload, you should:

1. initialize the process using [`createMultipartUpload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property) and store the returned `UploadId` (you'll need it for chunk uploads)
2. implement a [Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams) stream that would process data coming from the input stream
3. implement a [PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream which would buffer the data in large enough chunks before using [`uploadPart`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#uploadPart-property) to push them to S3 (under the `UploadId` returned in step 1)
4. track the returned `ETags` and `PartNumbers` from chunk uploads
5. use the tracked `ETags` and `PartNumbers` to assemble/finalize the file on S3 using [`completeMultipartUpload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#completeMultipartUpload-property)

Here's the [**gist of it**](https://gist.github.com/vsetka/6504d03bfedc91d4e4903f5229ab358c) in a working code example which streams a file from [iso.org](https://www.iso.org/), pipes it through gzip and into an S3 bucket. Don't forget to change the bucket name and make sure to run the lambda with 512mb of memory on node 6.10. You can use the code directly in the web GUI since there are no external dependencies.

**NOTE**: This is just a proof of concept that I put together for demonstration purposes. There is no retry logic for failed chunk uploads and error handling is almost non-existent which can literally cost you (e.g. [`abortMultipartUpload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#abortMultipartUpload-property) should be called upon cancelling the whole process to clean up the uploaded chunks since they remain stored and *invisible* on S3 even though the final file was never assembled). The input stream is being paused instead of queuing upload jobs and utilizing [backpressure](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/) stream mechanisms etc.

Comment: Your answer did not solve the OP's question of how to gzip chunks without reading and gzip the whole file.

Comment: How so? The input is being piped from the input stream through gzip and chunks parts uploaded as they come through.

Comment: Have you validated it? gzip can't do incremental zipping.

Comment: As far as I can tell it works as expected. If I pipe `inputStream` through a `PassThrough` filter before piping to `gzip`, I can see that the bytes move through the whole pipeline instead of gzip having to ingest the whole thing before compression. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: You have not got the full problem. Can you add a new file to existing gzip without decompressing or reading the existing archive with just appending?

Comment: I've re-read the OPs question/comments and in my opinion, they did not ask about **appending files** to an archive on S3, but rather how to stream a large amount of data (that can't be all held in memory) directly into a compressed file on S3. If the OP needs to write into **separate files** within the **same** archive, that should also be possible with a streaming archiver like `tar-stream`. The concept remains the same. Whether the data is coming from a single or multiple sources is not important as long as it's the same destination. Appending to an object, once finalized, is not supported.

Comment: Perhaps @Andremoniy would care to clear things up because otherwise, this is turning into a chat. It's pointless to continue discussing between the two of us which interpretation of the question is correct.

Comment: OP's is very clear of the question.  I'm not following this question from now. Want to make it clear this is not an answer and does not provide a solution.