# Stream tiny files directly to S3 into a zip with multipart upload utilizing parallel multiple Lambda's using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipart

I'll have 100's or 1000's of tiny pdf files that I'll need to zip into one big zip file and upload to S3. My currently solution is as follows:

1. NodeJS service send request with JSON data of all the pdf files I need to create and zip to a Lambda function
2. Lambda function processes data, creates each pdf file as buffer, pushes buffer into zip archiver, finalizes archive and then finally zip archive is streamed using PassThroughStream in chunks to S3.

I basically copied the below solution.

https://gist.github.com/amiantos/16bacc9ed742c91151fcf1a41012445e?permalink_comment_id=3804034#gistcomment-3804034

Now although this is a working solution, its not scalable and all of creating pdf buffer, archiving zip and upload to S3 happens in a single lambda execution which takes 20-30 seconds or more depending on the size of the final archived zip file. I have set the Lambda with 10GB memory and max 15 min timeout. Because for every 100MB of zip it requires 1GB of resources otherwise it times out due to max resources used. My zip could be 800MB or more sometimes which means it will require 8GB memory or more.

I want to use AWS multipart upload and somehow invoke multiple parallel lambda functions to achieve this. Its fine if I have to separate the creating the pdf buffers, zipping and s3 uploading into other lambdas. But I need to somehow optimize this and make it run parallely.

I see this post's answer with some nice details and example but it seems to be for a single large file.

[Stream and zip to S3 from AWS Lambda Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812992/stream-and-zip-to-s3-from-aws-lambda-node-js)

https://gist.github.com/vsetka/6504d03bfedc91d4e4903f5229ab358c

Any way I can optimize this? Any ideas and suggestions would be great. Keep in mind the end result needs to be one big zip file. Thanks

Comment: Multipart upload has some limitations on size that don't map well to parts of a zip file.  It would be possible to overcome them, and create a file like you want on the fly, but it's considerable work.  I'd start by reading up on how ZIP files are constructed, and how you'd need to create one manually so you could have multiple workers adding to one logical zip file.

Comment: If you attach an EFS file system to your lambda then you can design a workflow where the downloads are performed in parallel across multiple lambda executions, then once all have completed trigger the zip of all the files as one operation. If you use a separate lambda to do the zip then you can provide it enough memory and time to write the zip to EFS, upload it to S3 and then cleanup the EFS files.